# NameError: name 'get_frame' is not defined

Tags: python, import, importerror, nameerror, moviepy

I am trying to use [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) to import a frame from a video corresponding to a time `t`. There is a function named `get_frame` under the class `Clip` in the `moviepy` library. Now, when I try to access it, I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'get_frame' is not defined
```

This is the code I am trying to run

```
from moviepy.Clip import *

video = VideoFileClip("N:\Downloads\Browsers\myHolidays.mp4")
get_frame(video, 2)
```

What would be the right way to use the `get_frame` function with time `t` as an argument?

Also when I try to import get_frame from moviepy.Clip

```
from moviepy.Clip import get_frame
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name get_frame
```

However, I have no problem doing

```
from moviepy.Clip import copy
```

Is that because `copy` takes only one argument and `get_frame` takes two? I had no luck importing any other function with more than one argument this way as well. If that's the case, how should I import a function with two or more arguments?

Comment: I'd imagine you need to create a `Clip` instance and call the [`get_frame` *method*](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/Clip.html?highlight=clip#Clip.Clip.get_frame) on it. It's not a standalone function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: Well presumably `VideoFileClip` is a subclass of `Clip`, so... `video.get_frame(...)`? Have a look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Comment: I managed to import it using video.get_frame() and it returns a numpy.ndarray. Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe.